# If two quantum two-party states have the same entanglement, can they be transformed into each other by local unitary operation?

Tags: quantum-information

We know that local unitary operations will not change entanglement. But if two party state have the same entanglement in some measure, can they be related with local unitary operation?

Comment: "with local unitary operation" $\: \mapsto \:$ "with a local unitary operation" $\;\;\;$ or $\hspace{2.12 in}$ "with local unitary operation" $\: \mapsto \:$ "with local unitary operations" $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ ? $\hspace{2.16 in}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Local unitary operations do not change the spectrum of the reduced density matrix. Thus, *all* eigenvalues of the reduced density operator must be the same in both states.  On the other hand, if all eigenvalues of the RDM are equal, the states can be transformed into each other by local unitaries, since they have the same Schmidt coefficients. Note that for qubits, the Schmidt coefficients are specified by a single number (which corresponds to an entanglement measure).

(This is the case for pure states; for mixed states, things are more complicated.)

Comment: Does that mean for pure states in two-qubit systems, the answer to this question would be yes?

Comment: @Doris Yes. $\quad$